# Combining a list, map, and details on mobile

Tags: mobile, lists, maps

So I'm making an event app for mobile devices. Currently there's a map with icons, with different icons representing different kind of events, and then details pop up at the bottom of the screen when the icon is tapped.

Would it make sense to offer a list type view of all the events around? While the icons are nice for a quick see through of what's going on, I'm concerned it's too much work to tap through the icons and see the event details, event title, and basic information such as that.

The only problem is on a small screen like a mobile device I can't find any way to easily add a list option as well as a map, I could make it two separate screen but then the user loses out on being able to quickly see where an event is taking place.

How would y'all tackle this problem? Thank you.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to design for a bigger space when you don't have a lot of space. The downside of trying to fit everything in one view is that there might be too much information and it just ends up overwhelming the user. As you said, a mobile device only has a small screen, so don't try to squeeze everything thing in if you don't know that it is easier for the user to consume the information that way.

Comment: That's true, would however a popup or slide out list make sense? Say something like [this](https://developer.android.com/design/media/navigation_drawer_holo_dark_light.png) and selecting an item closes the slideout and centers the map on the event location/icon. I feel like this would be a relatively unobtrusive way to let the user decide how to peruse the events, however it is somewhat unconventional as slideout drawers are typically used for switching between screens.

Comment: Depends on how many things you want to show... in your case I think some type of toggle to switch between the 'views' should suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at how the Google Maps app tackles this on a phone.

If you want to see it in action, I've recorded a small video from my phone: [Google Maps search results UI on Android [youtube.com]](https://youtu.be/gxMmslXkByQ)

**In my opinion**, it's the best way to execute that kind of feature.

*Small note: On the first time, Maps shows a small "tooltip" to indicate that you can swipe left/right on the small card to browse results.*

Comment: That's very clever. Thank you for pointing that out to me!